# How to retrieve data from specific rows in MySQL inside android app?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I searched it here and also google it but as I'm beginner there were nothing to clear it to me. 
I create a database using php and mysql in which there are some columns ( id , name , category , price ...) and In my android app I have some buttons which names are as same as categories to retrieve data from database . I can show all rows data in list but can not filter them by category.
here is my **showData.php** file

```js
<?php

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
        include 'connection.php';
        showItems();
    } 

    function showItems(){

        global $connect;

        $connect->set_charset("utf8");

        $query = "Select * FROM items ORDER BY name; ";

        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
        $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        $temp_array = array();

        if($number_of_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $temp_array[] = $row;
            }
        }

        header('Connect-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array("items"=>$temp_array));
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }

?>
```

And in the app I'm using **Volley** to send request to the server and here is the link I use as url in Volley jsonObjectRequest

```js
String url = "http://mywebaddress.com/folder/showData.php";
```

To delete an Item or a row from the database I'm sending a specific link to **deleteItem.php**.
Here is the link

```js
String delete_url = "http://mywebaddress.com/folder/deleteItem.php?id="+ id;
```

And **deleteItem.php**

```js
 <?php

$response = array();
if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'user';
    $password = 'myPass';
    $dname = 'databaseName';

    $db = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dname);

    if ($db->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ("
        . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
    }

    $query =
            "DELETE FROM items WHERE id=?";
    $conn = $db->prepare($query);
    $conn->bind_param("i", $id);
    if ($conn->execute()) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Deleted Sucessfully.";
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Failed To Delete"; 
    } 

  echo json_encode($response);

    $db->close();
} else {
    echo 'Error!';
}
?>
```

As you can see in deleteItem.php I'm using " WHERE id=? " to point the row and getting the id from delete_url in the app.
Can I use something like deleteItem.php to filter rows by their category name?
How can I change showData.php to do it?
I can send link like delete_url for filter as below

```js
String filter_url = "http://mywebaddress.com/folder/filterCat.php?category=" +cat_name;
```

But how can I handle it in php?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Wouldn't `SELECT * FROM items WHERE cat = ?` work? What does your table structure for items look like?

Comment: Dave Chan. No. I tried that. but noting. It shows an error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM items WHERE category=?' at line 1

Comment: No, `$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM items WHERE cat = ?'); $db->bind_param('s', $_GET['category']); $db->execute()`. Then fetch your rows then. Looking at your deleteitem.php, it looks like you know how to bind and prepare statements.

Comment: It didn't work. So I do it inside android app, filter data using an if statement . And it's doing good . Of course it's not a good practice because my app should download all data and than filter and it may take some more time . I should learn more php then... thanks anyway